# Alternative methods for viewing flash content on the iPad?

Tags: ipad, adobe-flash

**Is there currently a way to view flash content on an iPad besides VNCing to a desktop computer?**

Currently you can connect a VNC client to a desktop computer to view flash content, but I am looking for alternative methods above and beyond that.

Is there any other ways to use Flash (and/or play Facebook games) on the iPad besides the VNC based method?

Comment: This is a loaded question that borders on unanswerable but rather than down vote it and close it - please edit it to make it more clear. There is no technical reason why a program can not be crafted to render flash, but it surely won't be hosted for sale or distribution on the Apple store anytime soon. It seems you are confusing things - VNC isn't "running on the iPad" What do you really want to know and edit the question to ask that.

Comment: I think the question could be correctly stated as : Is there any current way to view flash content on an iPad? As that is what a VNC connection to a desktop computer running a flash video would net you, albeit crappily.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Apple generally doesnt allow stuff like running some generic program on a virtual machine in their OS, but there are apps which do conversion and make it ready for an iOS device such as [iSWiFTER](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/iswifter/id388857173?mt=8), which even claims it can convert games.

I have never tried these out, but iSWiFTER is a 30 second free trial, so see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Splashtop](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/splashtop-remote-desktop/id382509315?mt=8) is an iPad app with desktop component that does a much better job of streaming video than other solutions.  Generally, you can fill the iPad's screen at 30fps with it over a wifi connection with no jitters. It claims audio support but I've not tested that part of it.  It should do just fine for streaming Flash

Answer (score 1):

Jailbreak then install Frash..

Comment: Don't do this. Flash eats batteries and offers security holes. There are reasons Apple doesn't support Flash on iOS. Pay attention to them, they know what hey are talking about.

Comment: @Stefan your comment is more appropriate to the original question (how to run Flash) than to my answer which is just a technical solution to the Q. Flash eats batteries but I'm sure the OP knows this, and any use uses batteries. Security holes? Sure. You need them to jailbreak, so I'm glad they are there. And Apple does not always know best.